React Native Realm testing
How can I test a Realm database made using React Native?
I have made the following table using Realm:
const exercises = {
    "name": "table",
    "properties": {
        "id": "int",
        "name": { "type": "string", "maxLength": 50 },
        "type": "string",
        "notes": { "type": "string", "maxLength": 500 },
        "video": "binary",
    },
    "primaryKey": "id",
};
const addRecord() => {}
const editRecord() => {}
const deleteRecord() => {}

I want to write tests to ensure the functions addRecord(), editRecord() and deleteRecord() work as expected.
Currently, I am using Jest to test the code. If possible, I would like to use Jest to test the table functions, although I am able to use other libraries.
I have tried making the table again in the realm.test.js file. However, I encounter the error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
> 1 | import Realm from "realm";

I have the following code in my package.json:
    "jest": {
        "preset": "jest-expo",
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@sentry/react-native|native-base|react-native-svg)"
        ]
    },

I have attempted to add the realm directory in the node_modules folder to the transformIgnorePatterns array. This has not worked

It would be helpful to know your coding platform and environment so tag the question with that info (iOS, Android etc)

It sounds like Realm is not loaded. Did you add it to your XCode project? It may also help to go through the Realm Setup Guide.  Also keep in mind that many Realm features and functions have been depreciated and will no longer exist after September 2025.

I have made multiple tables using the Realm package. Although I am not yet using the files for anything, they exist in my app. This does not cause any errors and I am still able to open all of the screens in my app.

Keep in mind that Realm has no tables; it's a NoSQL Document database. We still don't know your coding platform. A quick search on the internet reveals a number of other users encountering the same or similar issue - did you try searching? Here's one link with a workaround 6630 or maybe this or this

I have added the current Jest object in my package.json file to the question

I am not using any coding platform to run the tests. I am running the command npm test to test the application

Ok. How did you do this I have made the following table using Realm?

I have made the table in the file database/tables/table.js
I have not yet written any code to create, read, update or delete records
At the moment, I am trying to write tests to create, read, update and delete records
I am running the tests using npm test

This page shows how to create and perform CRUD processes on a Realm table: https://trycatchdebug.net/news/1415211/react-native-realm-testing
I want to test these processes, such as adding data to the table

Add @realm to the end of the transformIgnorePatterns Array.
The new object should be:
    "jest": {
        "preset": "jest-expo",
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@sentry/react-native|native-base|react-native-svg|@realm)"
        ]
    },

Run the tests like this:
describe("exercises table", () => {
const exercises = {
    "name": "table",
    "properties": {
        "id": "int",
        "name": { "type": "string", "maxLength": 50 },
        "type": "string",
        "notes": { "type": "string", "maxLength": 500 },
        "video": "binary",
    },
    "primaryKey": "id",
};
test("should write to the table", () => {
    const realm = new Realm({ "schema": [exercises] });
    realm.write(() => { realm.deleteAll(); });
    realm.write(() => {
        realm.create("exercises", { id: 1, name: "Exercise 1", type: "type 1", notes: "Note 1", "video": "Binary" });
    });
    const exercise = realm.objects("exercises")[0];
    expect(exercise.name).toBe("Exercise 1");
    expect(exercise.type).toBe("Type 1");
    expect(exercise.notes).toBe("Note 1");
    expect(exercise.video).toBe("Binary");
});
});

Define the table inside of the describe block. Write all of the tests inside of the same describe block
